# How to store data in browser local-storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I was trying not to use database but the browser local-storage for a login example. I mean when user give 'username' and 'password' it will check from browser local-storage and then be able to login.
I am using localStorage.setItem and localStorage.getItem of HTML5 to get the data and show it. 
Here is my Code-

```
var user_name=document.getElementById('userName').value;
var user_pswd=document.getElementById('password').value;                  
localStorage.setItem("user", user_name);
localStorage.setItem("pass", user_pswd);                    
// Retrieve                    
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("user");
```

It set the data and shows the user name,But is it possible to get the data after restarting the browser?? When I try to login for first time, how can I check with the browser data? Please any help is highly appreciated..

Comment: This does not look like a safe/sane thing to do.

Comment: Yaa I know but I have to do it that way.. Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Answer (score 3):

restarting browser does not delete local storage data.

you can check if you have data for both keys (userName , password) with following condition

```
if ((localStorage.getItem("userName") !== null) && (localStorage.getItem("password") !== null))
{
    // you have values for both userName and password
}
```

for your case you can test if textbox values match the values in local storage

```
if ((localStorage.getItem("userName") === null) && (localStorage.getItem("password") === null))
{
    localStorage.setItem("user", "Subho"); // writes name and password to local storage if not exists
    localStorage.setItem("pass", "Subho"); 
}

if ( (localStorage.getItem("user") == document.getElementById('userName').value)
{
    if ( (localStorage.getItem("pass") == document.getElementById('password').value)
    {
        // login is successful
    }           
}
```

however this is not a safe login method , local storage data is accesible by users

Comment: Thank u for ur ans, but can u explain some more.. Let username and paswrd both are 'Subho'. while login how will I check the the value of localStorage with the value of the textbox??

Comment: i have updated the answer , but i have to remind you that , this is not a recomended way for user login

Comment: is there any other way?? like session or anything??

Comment: Same question for me. How to store data using cache or using session? because local storage data is every-time displays on browser's console.